# Large deflection of a non prismatic cantilever beam under distributed load

Tags: beam, deflection

Here's what I got trying to calculate the large deflection of a cantilever beam with two different cross sections under a uniformly distributed load:
[image]
From the figure, the shear force is:
$$
V(s) = q(L-s)\cos(\theta)
$$
$\theta = \theta(s)$ being the deflection angle.
from the beam theory, the bending moment is:
$$
M(s) = EI(s)\frac{d\theta}{ds}
$$
we have:
$$
\frac{dM(s)}{ds} = V(s)
$$
we get:
$$
\frac{d}{ds}(EI(s)\frac{d\theta}{ds}) = q(L-s)\cos(\theta)\\
E\frac{dI(s)}{ds}\frac{d\theta}{ds}+EI(s)\frac{d^2\theta}{ds^2} = q(L-s)\cos(\theta)
$$
where:
$$I(s)=I1+H(s-L1)*(I2-I1)$$
in which $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function defined as:
$$H(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x\lt$ 0} \\
1, & \text{if $x\ge$ 0}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$\frac{dI(s)}{ds}=\delta(s-L1)*(I2-I1)$$
in which $\delta(s)$ is the Dirac delta function defined as:
$$\delta(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x\neq$ 0} \\
1,  & \text{if $x=$ 0}
\end{cases}$$
so, finding the deflection boils down to solving the boundary value problem of the nonlinear second order differential equation for $\theta(s)$:
$$EI(s)\frac{d^2\theta}{ds^2}+E\frac{dI(s)}{ds}\frac{d\theta}{ds}-q(L-s)\cos(\theta)=0$$
with the boundary conditions:
$$\theta(0)=0\\
\frac{d\theta}{ds}(L)=0$$
and the deformations in the y and x directions respectively:
$$y(s)=\int_0^s \sin(\theta)ds\\
x(s)=\int_0^s \cos(\theta)ds$$
Can anyone confirm these results? Thanks.

Comment: A first comment is that I dont see any need for the cos term in v(s). Unless you expect large deflections. However in that case The bending equation needs to include other terms (see raius of curvature).

Comment: @NMech Thank you for your response. I am in fact trying to calculate the large deflections of the beam as the title states but I'll add it to the post anyway to make it more clear. As for the bending moment equation, it has the derivative of the deflection angle which should be equivalent to the curvature, which in turn is the inverse of the radius of curvature, so I'm not sure I get your point there.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, because I just noticed, you are not using the commonly used Euler Bernoulli formula  I am most familiar with. I.e. $M= -EI \frac{d^2 w}{dx^2}$. In the [derivation for that formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Derivation_of_the_bending_equation), the radius of curvature is simplified from $R = \frac{(1+(y')^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{y''}$ to $R = \frac{1}{y''}$, which yields the bending equation. However, I don't recall ever seeing the form of the equation you provided. Could you provide some reference to it?

Comment: @NMech The formula for the bending moment should be $M=EI\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the curvature which is the inverse of the radius of curvature $R$. We also have $ds=Rd\theta$ so $\frac{d\theta}{ds}=\frac{1}{R}=\kappa$. Plugging this into the bending moment equation, we get the formula provided in the post $M=EI\frac{d\theta}{ds}$. The formula you provided is valid for small deflections where $\theta$ is approximately equal to $\frac{dw}{dx}$. You can check the article "Large Deflection of Cantilever Beams" by K. E. BISSHOPP and D. C. DRUCKER.

Comment: You were right. I was wrong. That is a valid formula for large displacements. Even now Ι havent had time to go through your post as diligently as it deserves. It is of a high quality we seldom see. However i will hazard further embarrassment, by asking if you are worried about the final results. To me they look like x and y define a perfect circle or am i again misinterpetting something?

Comment: @NMech My only and biggest concern is whether the use of the Heaviside function and -supposedly- its derivative the Dirac delta function to describe the changing moment of inertia is valid. I tried using Ansys for verification but I'm not all that familiar with it, so I thought I'd get some insight here. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by x and y defining a perfect circle but, I got them simply from the fact that: $\frac{dy}{ds}=sin\theta$ and $\frac{dx}{ds}=cos\theta$. Thanks.